# Convert files with new lines to list

Tags: bash

I want `SAMPLES` to be a list of items in the `SRR_Acc_list.txt` newline-delimited file.

I tried:

```
SAMPLES = cat "./input/SRR_Acc_list.txt" | tr -d '\n'
```

Input:

```
SRR9200813
SRR9200814
SRR9200815
SRR9200816
SRR9200817
```

Expected output:

```
SAMPLES = ["SRR9200813", "SRR9200814", "SRR9200815", "SRR9200816", "SRR9200817"]
```

Comment: I think you're going down the wrong path. You're using an all upper case variable name, putting blanks around the `=`, not using the correct syntax to save the output of a command, have a Useless Use Of Cat, are deleting all your newlines which would turn your command output into something that's no longer a valid text file, and showing expected output which isn't valid shell syntax and so is ambiguous about what you want. Given that, any answer you get is unlikely to be what you should really be doing for whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] which includes a minimal script showing how you would set `SAMPLES` manually and what you then want to do with it then we can help you but right now this looks a lot like a [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
mapfile -t ary < <(sed 's/.*/"&"/' "./input/SRR_Acc_list.txt")
printf "[%s]\n" $(IFS=,; echo "${ary[*]}")
```

Output:

```
["SRR9200813","SRR9200814","SRR9200815","SRR9200816","SRR9200817"]
```

- `mapfile` assigns an array `ary` to the contents of the newline delimited
  file.
- Setting `IFS` to a comma generates a comma separated list with `"${ary[*]}"`. The modification of `IFS` is limited within the subshell `$(...)` and does not affect other following commands.

Comment: That is very beautiful and clean :)

Comment: Similar alternative:  `mapfile -t a < SRR_Acc_list.txt ; printf "%s " "${a[@]}" | sed -e 's/^/["/;s/ $/"]/;s/ /", "/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your command to use the xargs command to convert the newline-delimited file to a list of items separated by spaces, and then wrap the output in square brackets to create a list.

Here's an example command that should work:

```
SAMPLES=$(cat "./input/SRR_Acc_list.txt" | xargs echo | tr ' ' '\n' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | tr '\n' ',')
SAMPLES="[$(echo ${SAMPLES::-1})]"
```

You will get the output:

```
$ echo $SAMPLES
["SRR9200813","SRR9200814","SRR9200815","SRR9200816","SRR9200817"]
```

This command does the following:

1. Reads the newline-delimited file using `cat`
2. Uses `xargs` to convert the newline-delimited file to a list of items separated by spaces
3. Uses `tr` to replace spaces with newlines
4. Uses `sed` to wrap each item in double quotes
5. Uses `tr` to replace newlines with commas
6. Wraps the output in square brackets to create a Python list

Note that the final `SAMPLES` variable includes the trailing comma, which may cause syntax errors in some Python code. You can remove the trailing comma manually, or modify the command to remove it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Or an `awk` alternative:

```
SAMPLES=$( awk 'BEGIN{printf "["} {if(NR==1){printf "\x22%s\x22",$1}else{printf ",\x22%s\x22",$1}}END{printf "]"}' SRR_Acc_list.txt )
echo $SAMPLES 
["SRR9200813","SRR9200814","SRR9200815","SRR9200816","SRR9200817"]
```

1. Print a square bracket
2. For the first line, print the item wrapped in quotes
3. For all subsequent lines, print the item wrapped in quotes preceded by a comma
4. After all lines were process, print the closing square bracket

Comment: Without double quotes in the `echo` command, `bash` interprets the variable contents and the output looks very different from what you showed.

Comment: Not in my shell @Cyrus - the above is copy & pasted. In fact the output looks identical when I wrap the variable in double quotes.

Comment: Interesting. Which shell and which version do you use?

Comment: `bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I use the same version. It must be some configuration parameter on my system. On other systems I don't have this problem and get the output you showed. From `SAMPLES=[SRR9200813]; echo $SAMPLES` I get this output: `1 2 3` Strange.

Comment: How weird ... a locale thing?

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s SRR_Acc_list.txt <<'EOF'
  g/./s/^/"/\
  s/$/", /
  ,j
  s/^/SAMPLES = [/
  s/, $/]/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Or you could create an `ed` script `script.ed`, name it to your own hears content,

The `script.ed`

```
g/./s/^/"/\
s/$/", /
,j
s/^/SAMPLES = [/
s/, $/]/
,p
Q
```

---

Now run:

```
ed -s SRR_Acc_list.txt < script.ed
```

---

In *one_line*

```
printf '%b\n' 'g/./s/^/"/\\\ns/$/", /' ',j' 's/^/SAMPLES = [/' 's/, $/]/' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s SRR_Acc_list.txt
```

---

Output

```
SAMPLES = ["SRR9200813", "SRR9200814", "SRR9200815", "SRR9200816", "SRR9200817"]
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in_place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.
- See GNU [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- See POSIX [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)